# Only some binaries are visible in pycharm python venv

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pycharm, virtualenv

I check for the existence of installed tools via `shutil.which()`
Both tools are installed via `apt get install ffmpeg mediainfo` and their binaries are located in /usr/bin with the same file flags and ownership in the host system:

```
lala@lala:/usr/bin$ ls -la ff*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 301544 May 19  2022 ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  22920 Feb 14  2022 ffmpegthumbnailer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 149984 May 19  2022 ffplay
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178832 May 19  2022 ffprobe
lala@lala:/usr/bin$ ls -la media*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47352 Apr  3  2022 mediainfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 374000 Apr  3  2022 mediainfo-gui
```

BUT within the virtual environment only one of them is available. The other one simply doe not exist

```
sh-5.1$ /usr/bin/ffmpeg 
ffmpeg version 5.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
[... more ...]

sh-5.1$ /usr/bin/mediainfo
sh: /usr/bin/mediainfo: No such file or directory
```

So what could be the reason, why one binary is available and the other one is not.

**Edit: this happens only in the termial / execution environment within pycharm**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Pycharm installed by flatpak has its own "environment" where one of the binaries was installed - the other one was not.